# insert values to MySQL if not exists

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table call **kpi** [id,key_competency,user].
for key_competency i have 4 default values (a,b,c,d). for each user they cannot have duplicate values for the key_competency.

so how do i query to check whether the key_competency value for the user have already existed or not. if not exist i want to allow the input of the value else i want reject.

Answer (score 2):

Create a unique index on combination of two columns ie. user and key_competency.

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_key_competency_unique
ON kpi(user,key_competency);
```

Further reference: [MySQL UNIQUE Index](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/)

Answer (score 0):

A unique index, as suggested by @Sanket is one way to go here.  You could also perform all your inserts using exists logic which checks for duplicates, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO kpi (key_competency, user)
SELECT 'a', 'Jon Skeet'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM kpi WHERE user = 'Jon Skeet' AND key_competency = 'a');
```